# Unable to Connect to online Redis Database

Tags: node.js, next.js, redis, node-modules

I am trying to connect to my redis database.

```
const redis = require('redis');

const client = redis.createClient({
  password: '<password>',
  socket: {
      host: '<host>',
      port: '<port>'
  }
});

async function Redisconnect() {
        await client.connect();
}
```

However, whenever I try to connect call the "Redisconnect" function i am approached with the error - TypeError: net.connect is not a function. I believe this error arises from this block of code with the "node_modules@redis\client\dist\lib\client\socket.js" file.

```
_RedisSocket_createNetSocket = function _RedisSocket_createNetSocket() {
    return {
        connectEvent: 'connect',
        socket: net.connect(__classPrivateFieldGet(this, _RedisSocket_options, "f")) // TODO 
    };
```

Fuethermore, I have used the "url" method,

```
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const client = createClient({
    url: 'redis://default:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT',
});

async function Clientconnect() {
    if (!client.isOpen()) {
        await client.connect()
    }
}

export { Clientconnect };
```

But, with this I am also given these errors - client.isOpen is not a function - The socket is already open - the client is closed. Any help is appreciated. I have replaced the "password", "host", and "port" values with the ones given to me by redis.

I am using Node.js v20.0.0. and Redis v4.6.5.

Comment: looks like client.isOpen is a property not a method ,
Try - Replace client.isOpen () with client.isOpen

Comment: Try to connect with the **url** option without the **default** word:
'redis://PASSWORD@HOST:PORT'